# Downgrading from Ubuntu 19.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, 19.04

I just installed 19.04 but now find that the primary thing I would like to use - TeX from MikTeX does not install. Added to this the fact that it wont be supported beyond 2020 makes me a little concerned. SO I'd like to downgrade or do a fresh reinstall of 18.04. The naive thing of repeating the booting process didnt seem to work. I suspect it didnt let me reinstall Ubuntu over the existing partition (since the disc system seems to have changed to the Linux one)

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is a standard release, with support for 9 months that is expected to be release-upgraded to 19.10, then 20.04 LTS - ie. it is supported by release-upgrading to the next release (LTS releases can do the same, but also have the ability to jump to next LTS release as well). Ubuntu 18.04 LTS can be re-installed over your existing installation if you want to go back, however I don't understand what your '*boot process didn't seem to work*' issue is (you should be specific, and did you verify the install-media is valid?)

Comment: Just installing 18.04 over the top will completely wipe the root partition, destroying local customizations (such as for samba, postfix, etc.)  Does anyone know how to actually "upgrade" to an older version?   BTW, I don't think the op meant that there was a boot problem, just that rebooting did not fix the other problem.  I want to know too, bc bluetooth headsets stopped working in 19.04